# MSChart insert, move, delete point

Tags: c#, windows-ce, mschart

First post here but been here 1000 times, really like the contribution from other members.
I know many of you will roll your eyes but I don't have a lot to start with.
I have moderate understanding of c#, basic of MS C and somewhat more of Microchip C and ASM.
Trying to make an app for WinCE6 as a home automation main controller, have most of my module working and no is time to put the pieces together, Have a SQLCE database with 50 column and 1440 rows, that is for 50 device and 1440 minute for 1 day, all control's will repeat their function every day. The database currently populated with random data for testing, now I want to create a visual control to create data, cant find CE version of MSChart control so I decided to make a x86 app where I can create my data. My difficulty mainly comes from inexperience, I can add or insert point to the Series but they will not insert in the order I want it to.

In this examples you can see what I would like to achieve;
1 no data point all 1440 record will have the same value.
2 added points to 200,400,600,800,1000,1100.
3 moved point at 400 on Y from270 to 350.
4 deleted point at 200,400,600,800.

Open to all suggestion.
Cant upload pictures so please follow the links.
Thanks

```
imgur.com/zsBla.jpg
imgur.com/y4wsn.jpg
imgur.com/Yo4XH.jpg
imgur.com/7FgHn.jpg


private void chart1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var pos = e.Location;
        clickPosition = pos;
        var results = chart1.HitTest(pos.X, pos.Y, false, ChartElementType.PlottingArea);
        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            if (result.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.PlottingArea)
            {
                var xVal = result.ChartArea.AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(pos.X);
                var yVal = result.ChartArea.AxisY.PixelPositionToValue(pos.Y);
                //tooltip.Show("x=" + xVal + ", y=" + yVal, this.chart1, e.Location.X, e.Location.Y - 15);
                tk++;
                chart1.Series[0].Points.InsertXY (0,tk,yVal);
                //chart1.Series[0].Sort(PointSortOrder.Ascending);//.Points.InsertXY(0,xVal, yVal);
                Tick.Text = tk.ToString();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: You want to add a point wherever you click on the chart ?

Comment: I know I'm asking to much but anyone could answere a simple question. How to create a infinite datapoint where no mater how may datapoint I enter it will alway hold its value, like with no other point it will just create a horizontal line.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your note there, yes I want to add point where've I click, actually I can do that right now, what I having problem is that I want point 0 and 1440 to stay there and add points beetwen them but the coordinata detecting I use its use pixels on the ploting area and not the full scale 1-1440

Comment: This is what happen if I insert point with sort http://i.imgur.com/C4wIZ.jpg and this when point's not sorted http://i.imgur.com/T9R7a.jpg

Comment: Try calling  Chart1.ChartAreas[0].RecalculateAxesScale()

Comment: That did not worked. http://youtu.be/W2zCxnVi71M

Comment: Haven't found my solution but there is a tons of very useful info here http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1591 , now I can drag the y of any point, also one of the problem whit my inserts that I inserting them into the beginning of the series.point index instead of between points...

Comment: I will have to satisfy with my latest result, anyone interested how is done check the MS Archive link in my previous note.  http://youtu.be/s_ICZiQ1HqE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elcast, looking over your issue it looks like your real problem is that you want your data to be "one-to-one", and you almost get it with your sorted data, but probably the actual problem is how you are sorting the data.

I put together a quick demo which I hope will help solve your problem:

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Chart1.Series(0).ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line
        Chart1.Series(0).Points.AddXY(0, 10)
        Chart1.Series(0).Points.AddXY(1440, 100)
        Chart1.Series(0).Points.AddXY(600, 80)

        Chart2.Series(0).ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line
        Chart2.Series(0).Points.AddXY(0, 10)
        Chart2.Series(0).Points.AddXY(1440, 100)
        Chart2.Series(0).Points.AddXY(600, 80)

        Chart1.DataManipulator.Sort(System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.PointSortOrder.Descending, Chart1.Series(0))

    End Sub
```

Which gives this (Left: Sorted, Right: Unsorted)
[image]